# How to test the WebSocket over head?

Tags: c#, testing, websocket, overhead, measure

I need to test the over head on my WebSocket application.  How to test it and see the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) you can track all the communication between your browser and the server using WebSockets.   (look in the log section).

This should allow you to get a feel for exactly what the communication looks like, including whatever you have defined as "overhead".

Answer (score 2):

I find the [WebSocket pane in Google Chrome's Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network) to be great for measuring and debugging WebSocket traffic.